# Can anybody figure out what I am doing wrong?

Tags: c++

This is my solution for a problem, I tried solving it until I can get the elast amount of compiler errors, but for this error Im not sure as to what it is telling me

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

#define MAX 99 
#define totaltriangle(w) ((1+(w-2))*(w/2)+w) 
#define totaldiamond(w) ((2+(w-2)+(w/2))*(w/2)+w) 

char triangle[totaltriangle(MAX)+MAX]; // array for the results 
char diamond[totaldiamond(MAX)+MAX]; 

int main(void) { 
    int width; 
    do{ // Get the diamond width 
        cout << "Diamond width: +;" 
        cin >> width; 
        cout << "Width = " << width << endl; 
    } while(width<1 || width>MAX || (width%2)==0); 

    // triangle 
    int tottri = totaltriangle(width)+width-1; 
    for(int i=0; i<tottri; i++){ 
        triangle[i] = '+'; 
    } 
    for(int i=1; i<=width/2; i++){ 
        int sq = i*i; 
        triangle[sq+i-1] = triangle[tottri-sq-i] = '\n'; 
    } 
    triangle[tottri] = 0; 
    cout << triangle <<endl; 

    // diamond 
    int tot = totaldiamond(width)+width-1; 
    int l=0; 
    for(int i=0; i<tot/2; l++, i++){ 
        for(int j=0; j<width/2-l; i++, j++){ 
            diamond[i] = ' '; 
            diamond[tot-i-2*(l+1)] = ' '; 
        } 
        diamond[tot-i-2*(l+1)] = '\n'; 
        for(int j=0; j<2*l+1; i++, j++){ 
            diamond[i] = '+'; 
            diamond[tot-i-1-l+width/2] = '+'; 
        } 
        diamond[i] = '\n'; 
    } 
    diamond[tot] = 0; 
    cout << diamond << endl; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Ive been trying to figure out what was wrong with this for hours but Im just a beginner right now so Im clueless right now as to what this means. Thanks for the help. This is my compiler error message Im getting.

```
./main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./main.cpp:16:2: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘cin’
cin >> width; 
^
```

Comment: `cout << "Diamond width: +;"` has the `;` inside the string, not at the end of the line.

Comment: It pays to read the error. `expected ‘;’ before ‘cin’`

Answer (score 2):

According to your own error message, the line:

```
cout << "Diamond width: +;"
//                       ^ no
```

should be:

```
cout << "Diamond width: +";
//                        ^ yes
```

Look at your error message again:

```
./main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./main.cpp:16:2: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘cin’
cin >> width; 
^
```

The correction I mentioned is made immediately before the `cin`. I didn't look at the rest of your code, but if you have additional problems, the error message is what you need to understand, so I'll try to break it down for you.

The line `./main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:` tells you the issue is in the `main.cpp` file, in the `main` function.

The line `./main.cpp:16:2: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘cin’` tells you the compiler is "looking" at line 16, column 2, which points to the beginning of the `cin >> width;` part mentioned last.

It's very straightforward.

Comment: Thank you I understand now, however after I corrected my code, it is now saying  ⇒     Checking output 
     ⇒     Your standard output  is not what was expected

Comment: @programmerihop: And how are you trying to debug it?

Comment: @programmerihop: Again, *how* are *you* trying to debug it? Telling me what it says is of limited usefulness. Also, it's generally frowned upon to link to external sites or provide images with error messages. Update your original post instead, if you really need to, and explicitly mark it as such.